# LoadError: no such file to load — curl

Tags: ruby

I just have a problem with a ruby script

I just want to change the directory where the following command would be executed

I try this code but it didn't work

```
  puts "Nom du dossier svn?"
  @dossier = gets.chomp
  system("cd #{@dossier}")
```

(it's in french because i'm french ^^)

Someone can help me ?

Thank you

Comment: What's the connection between the title, and the question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [`Dir.chdir`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Dir.html#M000620) function.

When you do:

```
system("cd dir")
```

This in effect starts a shell, that shell changes to the given directory and promptly exits. It has no effect whatsoever on the calling process (your ruby script).

Answer (score 3):

`system` spawn a subshell, that is this subshell that will change directory, then die.

You want your actual Ruby process to change directory, so use `Dir.chdir(@dossier)`